# Resolving ckeditor-duplicated-modules errors in context of Drupal

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I've built the sample plugins as described in CKE docs (https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/crea...) in the CKE environment (ie outside Drupal) and they all work. I've also adapted a couple of other plugins to work there in order to try to understand it better.

I'm trying to add the example Abbreviation plugin to Drupal by adapting the Drupal module ckeditor5_dev template.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/plugins/abbr...
I can get through part 1 OK but as soon as I try to add

```
 import ContextualBalloon from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui';
```

I build Ok then get the dreaded duplicate modules error in the browser console on reloading edit page:

*Uncaught CKEditorError: ckeditor-duplicated-modules*
*Read more: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules*

Following the help link, I tried to convert the Plugin and ButtonView to use full src path, but gives the same error (even without ContextualBalloon!) - can't understand why. The uncommented lines below work to get the plugin to the current point and the commented-out have been tried in attempts to get ContextualBalloon in.

```
import { Plugin } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';
//import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import { ButtonView } from 'ckeditor5/src/ui';
//import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';
//import ContextualBalloon from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/panel/balloon/contextualballoon';
//import { ContextualBalloon, clickOutsideHandler } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui';
```

Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to convert the CKE native plugin example module imports to the Drupal CKE style:

```
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin'; => import { Plugin } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';

import { ContextualBalloon} from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui'; => import { ContextualBalloon } from 'ckeditor5/src/ui';

import { FocusTracker, KeystrokeHandler } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils'; => import { FocusTracker, KeystrokeHandler } from 'ckeditor5/src/utils';

import Command from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/command'; => import { Command } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';

import findAttributeRange from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/utils/findattributerange';  => import findAttributeRange from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/utils/findattributerange';
```

There is a general pattern.
Note curly brackets round import name where the path is actually a subdirectory of modules rather than the path to an individual file (less leading 'node_modules' and trailing '.js')
Drupal's ckeditor5 module does not have a node_modules directory so incorporates the js modules from somewhere. More clues in `core/modules/ckeditor5/js/build/ckeditor5.types.jsdoc` and the plugins in

```
core/modules/ckeditor5/js/ckeditor5_plugins
```

Comment: Also try with yarn v1 it may resolve internally